# Unable to open process Runtime.getRuntime().exec on server when code is invoked using tomcat API

Tags: java, sockets, cmd, serversocket, processbuilder

I have created a rest API and executed added the below code in the rest API but when rest API is invoked by the client notepad.exe file is not opened on remote machine.
when we execute the same code using simple java program on remote server its opening the nodepad application. also when this code is invoked using API from client machine, notepad file is opened in background processes but I am not able to see the notepad prompt.
I have to execute some other .exe file in GUI mode, I am facing same issue for that application but I am taking the example of notepad, if I am able to fix this one that will automatically be fixed.

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
"cmd /c start notepad.exe",
null,
new File("C:\temp\"));

Comment: What is the point of a remote client opening a GUI program on the server, when there is no user to interact with the program? --- Anyway, if Tomcat is running as a Service, then it cannot run programs requiring the UI, because that is by default now allowed. For good reasons.

Comment: I want to execute neoload.exe tool with some arguments using tomcat and tomcat is hosted on a windows machine .

Comment: In short, i want to lauch a exe file on windows machine, end user have access to servers as well on web we are just triggering that .exe file with some arguments , currently exe file is running in background  but end user also want to view the output of application during run time right now .exe in running in background so at the end of the test user can view the logs